# How to upload an image selenium webdriver with javascript?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.css('div.border-right:nth-child(2)')), 1000)
.then((element) => {
element.click();
});
```

I am using java-script for my test cases. I had an issue to upload image, upto click the upload button i did. I don't know how to fetch the data from the system storage because `input` tag had a style as `display:none`. When I tried

`sendKeys()` --> **elementNotInteractable error** occurrs.

In this scenario how can I upload image using selenium webdriver in javascript  without test framework?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code of the page your are trying to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Robot class for image upload functionality.The following code works,

```
    driver.findElementByXPath("locate the file upload button']").click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("specify the path where your file is located");
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. But i want in javascript for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files in selenium is done by using the `sendKeys()` method in case of the file-select button/field has 'input' tag. For instance:

```
WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.id("IdName"));
uploadElement.sendKeys("C:\filename.pdf")
```

Otherwise, you can use a Robot class or Autoit for same.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working in a testing company on the automation part then upload file scenario is the most common problem. There are 03 ways to automate the same.

1. Using selenium
2. Using AutoIT
3. Using Robot class

**Using Selenium:** We can simply upload it using selenium if the HTML contains attribute input[@type='file']. if this thing is not present in the HTML part of the application then it won't be possible using selenium then we need to look into another alternative. If it is present then we can use below syntax for the same.

```
WebElement upload_file = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='file_upload']"));
upload_file.sendKeys("C:/Users/abc/Desktop/upload.jpg");
```

**Using AutoIT:**
Open the AutoIT editor.
We need to write a simple code in AutoIT editor, required for file upload operation (the name of the file to be uploaded, will be mentioned in the code).
Now close the editor and right click on it, you will see compile script option.
Choose compile script (x64) option for 64 bit machine and go with compile script (x86) for a 32-bit machine.
As soon as the above step is completed, a .exe file is created and this file will be mentioned in our selenium eclipse code.
After compilation‘fileupload.exe’ file gets created.
Now we can make use of this file in the Selenium web driver script.

```
WebElement browser = d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pimCsvImport_csvFile']"));   //Browse button
browser.click();                                
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Chait\\Desktop\\autoit\\fileupload.exe");
  Thread.sleep(3000);
 
WebElement upload = d.findElement(By.id("btnSave"));     //Uploadbutton
upload.click();     
System.out.println("File Uploaded Successfully");   // Confirmation message
```

When the program executes this line, it goes through the fileupload.exe file where the AutoIT code is executed as shown below:
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1","C:\Users\Chait\Desktop\autoit\data_file.csv")
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")

**Robot Class**
Its already covered above using the same we can upload.